# All polymorphic models of one type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So, I have the following models:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
  # Table has a favoritable_id and favoritable_type
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable
end

class Magazine < ActiveBoard::Base
  has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites
end
```

When I make a call:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.favorites
```

It brings back all favorites books and magazines as expected (basically what it looks like in database with the favoritable_id and favoritable_type columns/properties).  When I call this:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.favorites.books
```

I get an error that says:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'books' ...
```

However, calling:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.favorites.first.favoritable
```

This works fine.

I'm not quite getting how can I get all the favorite book models in this sort of setup?  I'm I doing it wrong?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this way:

```
user.favorites.map {|f| f.favoritable}
```

Or, to get the favorite books only, do this:

```
user.favorites.select { |f| f.favoritable_type == 'book' }.map { |f| f.favoritable }
```

Comment: Okay, this works but returns all models of favorite  (all magazines and books). How can I get only the books?

Comment: Okay, this works but returns all models of favorite (all magazines and books). How can I get only the books?

Comment: Try again the updated answer :) `favoritable_type` is `book` in the db? then the updated answer will work.

Comment: AWESOME :) Glad it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily define relation between `User` and `Book`s and `Magazine`s using the code shown below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_books, through: :favorites, source: :favoritable, source_type: 'Book'
  has_many :favorite_magazines, through: :favorites, source: :favoritable, source_type: 'Magazine'
end
```

Now you can easily query user's books and magazines:

```
 user.favorite_books
 user.favorite_magazines
```

Books query produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "books"."id" = "favorites"."favoritable_id"
WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = ? AND
      "favorites"."favoritable_type" = ?
      [["user_id", 1], ["favoritable_type", "Book"]]
```

As you can see, all the job on selecting Book is done in database. Which is much more efficient then taking full favorites list to the client and filtering it there.

One more advantage of this approach is that it's scales well. For instance, if you want to know which Jules Verne's books are favorited by the given user, it's very natural to query:

```
user.favorite_books.where('books.author = ?', 'Jules Verne')
```

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam giving `just enough` response is not the way SO should be done. I think we all should strive for better and even better answers. If you can show me a better way to solve the problem, I will be really happy to learn from you.

Comment: @dimakura I really like your solution.  However, how would I accomplish this if I still want it to look like?  users.favorites.books? or users.favorites.magazines?  Is that even possible?  Or another solution... users.favorite_books? I'm new to Rails, so forgive me on this stuff...

Comment: @Sean, users.favorites.books is not possible. But user.favorite_books is achievable. I've updated my answer accordingly (for magazines too).

Comment: @dimakura I have deleted my previous comments as you have updated your answer. You can delete your prior comments if you want as they are irrelevant now. Thanks.